# Phonegap 1.9.0 and Android 4.1 <input type="text" /> not taking input after some inputs

Tags: android, html, cordova, mobile-application, phonegap-build

Phonegap 1.9.0 and Android 4.1  not taking input after some inputs.
With the release of PhoneGap 1.9.0 and Android4.1, in a samsung galaxy s3 phone and a simulator could not enter characters in an inputbox, now in PhoneGap version 1.9.0 and the same version of Android after some inputs I can not go to enter any character in any inputbox.

Comment: Can you clarify your question ?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm having the exact same issue, but I'm not using PhoneGap (just native WebView with JavascriptInterfaces) - you can read my question here - http://goo.gl/r0l5R5